# Running into an error when trying to implement Keras

Tags: python-2.7, keras

I'm using Python 2.7, Windows 7, and Keras 1.2.1 (Keras2 seems to be having a lot of compatibility issues with different PC/Python configs,  so I was recommened to use 1.2.1)
 I'm using a script from Practical Deep Learning For Coders, Part 1 Course

```
import utils; reload(utils)
from utils import plots
```

The error I"m getting is as below

`Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
"g++" -shared -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"c:\python27\include" -I"c:\python27\lib\site-packages\theano\gof" -L"c:\python27\libs" -L"c:\python27" -o C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.12-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.12-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -lpython27`

I can't decipher what this means. Google search brought up a Chinese message board.

It seems to be  a g++ problem as the previous warning I got was as follows:
`WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda:`conda install m2w64-toolchain``.  Despite installing m2w64-toolchain afterwards, I was continuing to get the same warning.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same problem, because it seems to lack an actual error message.... But, in case it's a g++ issue, you probably need to have visual studio installed, or a compatible C++ compiler. -- See here for the versions you need: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: yeah it's a g++ problem as the previous warning I got was as follows:
`WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: conda install m2w64-toolchain`.  Despite installing m2w64-toolchain afterwards, I still received the same warning. So I'm guessing it's path problem?

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual C++ installed already, as I needed it for some other framework.

Comment: You need a specific version of the compiler. For python 2.7, you need C++ V9.0, which matches Visual Studio 2008, is that the version you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I reinstalled Anaconda.
And then via command line I wrote `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
This time I didn't get a message stating that m2w64 was already installed. I'm assuming it was a path issue and this time reinstalling everything from the start also created a new path?

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem. But I can't seem to close this question; I have to wait another two days.

Comment: Isn't it just check your own answer as valid?

Comment: I'm getting a "you can accept your own answer in two days" message that's preventing me.   :(

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting things I learned while trying to configure theano and keras:

**C++/g++**

- Depending on your python version, you have to install a corresponding version of the C++ compiler, or Visual Studio. Ex: Python 2.7 needs C++ 9.0 (Visual Studio 2008). But Python 3.5 needs C++ 14.0 (Visual Studio 2015) -- See here for more: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers
- I also had to install MinGW for g++ compilers: https://nuwen.net/mingw.html
- Even with it correctly installed, you may see an error about `hypot`. This question shows two possible solutions: [g++ error on import of Theano on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536788/g-error-on-import-of-theano-on-windows-7)
- I tried installing everything via Conda, but all calculations were slower than continents moving away from each other. Then I gave up conda and installed everything via standard python. (First python, then numpy, then scipy, then theano, then keras). Not sure if MinGW goes before of after numpy/scipy, but I think it goes before.

**BLAS/LAPACK**

- Numpy and theano may warn you that no lapack/blas is installed. For that, I used the numpy and scipy libraries available here, they're great and fast: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- Another option is installing MKL directly from Intel, before installing numpy and scipy.

**Path problems / Invalid Token - ldflags**

- Avoid installing anything, including the MKL, in folders containing spaces in their names! That will definitely confuse theano/numpy.
- You may get "invalid token" errors if you have spaces in folders, and a `ldflags` var described in that error. To solve that, either reinstall your mkl libraries in folders without spaces, or configure the `.theanorc` file in the theano home folder with your `[blas]` configuration and the `ldflags` var. (See here: [Receive AssertionError while optimizing convolution in theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020075/receive-assertionerror-while-optimizing-convolution-in-theano))
- Since I wasn't willing to reinstall MKL in another folder, I learned to create symbolic links to windows. (in the answer above)
- Replace the folders with space in the theano config and also in the numpy config files (`__config__.py`), you can see its content with `np.__config__.show()`. (See answer above)

Comment: I use Python 3.6 (have 2.7 installed as well) but the notebooks I'm studying from use version 2.7, so was forced to adapt. I plan to install Keras with my 3.6 version, so I hope I don't run into compatibility issues. I seem to have Visual Studio 2008 installed.

Comment: I suggest you use python 3.5 instead (I haven't read anywhere that keras/theano/tensorflow are compatible with 3.6, but they do specify 3.5). For python 3.5, you'll need C++ 14.0 (VS 2015).